# Is nginx proxy can be use for this use case?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have been having trouble understanding the concept of proxy and want to know if it is possible to use in my use case. I have a web folder with one php file foo.php, I want to know if someone access not existing file for eg bar.php and then can I get that location in nginx config and show in that url but take contents from foo.php. I'm trying to do something like this in nginx but I
m not sure if my thinking is right.

```
location bar.php {
proxy_pass http://localhost/foo.php;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both locations are on the same webserver you don't need proxy actually. You can just use location/alias for this. See these examples on how to do this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399789/nginx-how-to-create-an-alias-url-route
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490391/how-to-properly-configure-alias-directive-in-nginx
- [Serving PHP from an Nginx Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/418565/serving-php-from-an-nginx-alias)

As for the proxy it is usually useful when you want to serve content for *other* webserver (be it physically other or just another software running on the same host, i.e. like apache+nginx configurations).

Comment: "apache+nginx", both webservers and popular reverse proxies, why would you have them both?  Wouldn't "(nginx|apache)+php" be more sensible?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille apache as a backend for nginx was used quite often back in past as a transition between moving from pure LAMP stack to LNMP. Including those .htaccess or other apache tied configurations. Another example would be where webapp uses some apache modules. Usually nginx was used to serve static content while proxying dynamic php requests to apache. It's still possible to find such configurations.

Comment: Where the transition never finished?  But if you really need the .htaccess, then stick to Apache.  Nginx seems to be faster, but I've never known Apache to be the bottleneck.  Its configuration is a science, or voodoo, that's true.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I'm not aware of current situation but it was quite common just a few years ago. Adding nginx to serve static content only had some benefits and a huge speed boost to a sites with a lot of small static files. One of the articles describing this setup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache

Answer (score 2):

Nginx can certainly achieve this, but it's probably an internal rewrite you're looking for.

```
location bar.php {
    rewrite . foo.php;
}
```

Nginx will check its configuration for how to run foo.php, and when that succeeds, it will seem to the user as if bar.php was run.  See NStorm's answer for how to configure "location ~ .php$".